# How can I reduce the file size of a scanned PDF file?

Tags: pdf, compression

I have a 72.9 MB PDF file that I need to shrink to 500 KB or below.

The file was a JPEG image that I had scanned and then converted to PDF.

Comment: it depends on what consumes the space...need a lot more information.  compressing image space could help, but if you're trying a large file heap spray, that won't work.  seriously need more info.

Comment: convert it to DjVu, instead trying to reduce to impossible sized PDF (according source)

Comment: It only seems to help filesize a little bit, but `pdfopt` has a simple syntax and improves loading and page-turning speed in the iPad era. :-)

Comment: PDF to PS is not effective in scanned PDF file, I try to convert 56 MB pdf into ps file but ps file convert into 1.3 GB and again ps2pdf is converted in 45 MB file

Comment: Please see [this related Q&A](http://askubuntu.com/questions/280312/gui-program-to-resize-pdf-documents-and-change-their-dpi?lq=1) for a number of GUI front ends to ghostscript that should make the process of reducing PDF filesizes easier.

Comment: Note that the OP appears to have accidentally marked the wrong answer as accepted.  His accompanying comment gives thanks for the ghostscript solution, which solved the problem, but ghostscript appears not in this answer but in a different one.

Comment: I've tried nearly all answers from below to get a ~10MB pdf to below required 1MB and only [shrinkpdf](http://www.alfredklomp.com/programming/shrinkpdf/) worked for me. Here I could fine tune the dpi and also grey-scale it to get a still readable but compact version. Great tool!

Answer (score 236, accepted):

aking1012 is right. With more information regarding possible embedded images, hyperlinks etc.. it would be much more easier to answer this question!

Here are a couple of script and command-line solutions. Use as you see fit.

- [reduce-pdf-file-size-linux](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/reduce-pdf-file-size-linux)
- [shrinkpdf](http://www.alfredklomp.com/programming/shrinkpdf/)
- [compress-a-pdf-with-pdftk](http://pandemoniumillusion.wordpress.com/2008/05/07/compress-a-pdf-with-pdftk/)
- [pdfcompress](http://docupub.com/pdfcompress/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions, the ghostscript shell worked wonders and shrank it down to 460KB :)

Comment: That is not necessarily true. If the content went from an image to text, that is more than fessible. [That is assuming that the text is accurately ocred]

Comment: I recommend you shrinkpdf.sh script, you can customize the code to use the ppi value you want (72 by default) and reach exactly the filesize you need to sacrifice the least quality. This made me able to upload a scanned document of 11 MB with a max. size of 3 MB without losing a lot of quality.

Comment: shrinkpdf works great!

Comment: First link, with setting "/ebook", reduced a 19MB scanned file to 4.2MB and the scanned text remains readable.

Comment: Where is the ghostscript shell that the OP is referring to https://askubuntu.com/questions/113544/how-can-i-reduce-the-file-size-of-a-scanned-pdf-file#comment134224_113547?

Comment: shrinkpdf worked for me! You must install ghostscript and ensure the command 'gs' is available in PATH for this to work. In macos you can install ghostscript using 'brew install ghostscript"

Comment: @user13107 It is this answer - https://askubuntu.com/a/256449/171427

Comment: For me, https://docupub.com/pdfcompress/ [**pdfcomress**], got the best results.

Comment: First link, /ebook setting, reduced 2.2MiB PDF to 144,5KiB

Comment: First link is a long page for a gs one-line command line. Second is best, a flexible script http://www.alfredklomp.com/programming/shrinkpdf/ . Third is limited (convert to ps and back to pdf, no options). Fourth implies sending your PDF to an unknown third party online (but hey, it's *free*!), no thanks. So, I recommend http://www.alfredklomp.com/programming/shrinkpdf/

Answer (score 1088):

Use the following [Ghostscript](https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) command:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook \
-dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf
```

Summary of `-dPDFSETTINGS`:

- `-dPDFSETTINGS=/screen` lower quality, smaller size. (**72 dpi**)
- `-dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook` for better quality, but slightly larger pdfs. (**150 dpi**)
- `-dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress` output similar to Acrobat Distiller "Prepress Optimized" setting (**300 dpi**)
- `-dPDFSETTINGS=/printer` selects output similar to the Acrobat Distiller "Print Optimized" setting (**300 dpi**)
- `-dPDFSETTINGS=/default` selects output intended to be useful across a wide variety of uses, possibly at the expense of a larger output file

[Reference](https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/latest/VectorDevices.html#controls-and-features-specific-to-postscript-and-pdf-input):

> #### Controls and features specific to PostScript and PDF input
>
> `-dPDFSETTINGS=configuration`
>
> Presets the "distiller parameters" to one of four predefined settings:
>
> - `/screen` selects low-resolution output similar to the Acrobat Distiller (up to version X) "Screen Optimized" setting.
> - `/ebook` selects medium-resolution output similar to the Acrobat Distiller (up to version X) "eBook" setting.
> - `/printer` selects output similar to the Acrobat Distiller "Print Optimized" (up to version X) setting.
> - `/prepress` selects output similar to Acrobat Distiller "Prepress Optimized" (up to version X) setting.
> - `/default` selects output intended to be useful across a wide variety of uses, possibly at the expense of a larger output file.

The exact settings for each of these, including their DPI values, are shown in the dozens of options in [this table](https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/latest/VectorDevices.html#distiller-parameters).

Comment: One can also make a Nautilus script to access this function for every file.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. ghostscript is *the* PDF, XPS and PS implementation for unices and can do basically everything delivering best quality...

Comment: @Sina: There is actually a Nautilus Script with a simple Zenity-based GUI that utilizes this gs command with all its quality-level options: https://launchpad.net/compress-pdf

Comment: This is the right answer for this question (compressing a pdf that is mostly bitmap data). I found that the `screen` setting was too low quality for me, but `ebook` worked well, cutting a 33Mb scan-based PDF down to 3.6Mb, and keeping it very readable. Other options for the `-dPDFSETTINGS` option are listed here: http://milan.kupcevic.net/ghostscript-ps-pdf/, and it might be a good idea to include them in this answer.

Comment: The high quality default compressed a PDF scan in black&white from 38.2 MB to 6.4 MB without any significant quality loss. Apparently the original encoding was very inefficient. Thank you!

Comment: @pietrodn, the original encoding was probably a bitmap. If it saves every single pixel without compression, I would't call that inefficient. Rather, it seems like GS just does a good job at compressing.

Comment: Any GUI for this?

Comment: on 17.10 it made 42 mb pdf to 127 mb :(

Comment: My pdf file size increased too... :(

Comment: Based on this, I created a handy script called pdf_compress.sh @ https://github.com/erikw/dotfiles/blob/personal/bin/pdf_compress.sh

Comment: I used these instructions to compress a PDF. However, I get a lot of errors. I described the issue [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/525486/102825) in detail. I would appreciate it if you could take a look and help me with that.

Comment: Is the dCompatibilityLevel value important? Can it change over different ghostscript releases?

Comment: With Ubuntu 20.04 and gs 9.50, this failed with a Segmentation Falt ...

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04 it ran just fine, decreasing a 3 pg PDF from 3.8MB to 330KB, but it is completely unreadable. Looks like it is like 25DPI. Horribly pixelated. Here's the cmd I ran: `gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf`.

Comment: ...and the other settings look great, but don't decrease the PDF size at all. :( Note this is on OCRed output from my [`pdf2searchablepdf`](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/PDF2SearchablePDF) program.

Comment: Looks like this cmd is saved as a gist by somebody here too: https://gist.github.com/firstdoit/6390547.

Comment: I was mistaken the other day, using `-dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook` actually works fine. Example: `gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=out.pdf in.pdf`. This is very similar to (if not identical to?) `ps2pdf -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook in.pdf out.pdf`, since `ps2pdf` is actually just a wrapper around Ghostscript (`gs`), apparently. Also, for `-dPDFSETTINGS=` reference see https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/VectorDevices.htm#PSPDF_IN, as well as this table here: https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/VectorDevices.htm#distillerparams.

Comment: I've added an answer here now, stemming from this and other answers: https://askubuntu.com/a/1303196/327339.

Comment: This has been completely useless every time I've tried it, no matter what scanner the original images have come from and what quality settings I've used.

Comment: **Do not use this.**  `/ebook`, `/screen`, etc downsample the PDF i.e. they reduce the number of pixels - a horribly inefficient/lossy way to compress a PDF.  Instead of downsampling, use image compression - it results in a much nicer final result (at least when you have enough pixels): `convert -density 300 input.pdf -quality 30 output.pdf`

Comment: This worked pretty well, but gave several instances of this error: `**** Error: File encountered 'rangecheck' error while processing an image. Output may be incorrect.` and seems to have deleted some of the images in the source PDF.

Comment: Getting: `Failed to initialise downsample filter, downsampling aborted`

Comment: @Zaz, the `convert` command you gave (`convert -density 300 input.pdf -quality 30 output.pdf` just took a _searchable_ 962 KB file and made it a _non-searchable_ **4.5 MB** file, making the "compressed" PDF **nearly 5x larger**. That's definitely not the command I'm looking for.

Comment: @GabrielStaples: Sorry. To clarify, ImageMagick's `convert` is only for PDFs that are just images. So if you scan a document, `convert` will work better than the command above because it will compress the pages instead of downsampling them (reducing the number of pixels).

Comment: Used this on a PDF file containing vector images and it seemed to work fine. However, after compression some of the vector images only show up as black boxes, but only in Safari. Other viewers or browsers (Chrome/Firefox) work perfectly fine.

Comment: Worked great on my Mac as well (Homebrew gs)

Answer (score 298):

My favorite way to do this is to convert the PDF to PostScript and back. It does not always work, though, but when it works the results are nice:

```
ps2pdf input.pdf output.pdf
```

This also directly works on PDFs, as suggested in the comments.

Some users also report more success when using [the ebook settings](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/VectorDevices.htm#distillerparams) as follows:

```
ps2pdf -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook input.pdf output.pdf
```

Comment: Despite the fact that this one approach became my favorite solution to compress pdf files, it breaks up url links the document may have (which does not happen with @Michael D's approach). Apart from that, awesomeness is all I can think of running this snippet! (:

Comment: @Rubens Ah. Did not know about the fact that it breaks the url links. Thanks for adding that.

Comment: This bypasses password protection...just sayin'

Comment: Great solution! In contrast to printing to a postscript file in Evince, the quality didn't noticeably change.

Comment: For the second command, I would use this shorthand: `ps2pdf output.{ps,pdf}`

Comment: ps2pdf will take pdfs as inputs, so you can do this in one step: `ps2pdf intput.pdf output.pdf`

Comment: This command has actually increased the size of a pdf from Google books 10 times! But at least my Kindle now displays all characters in this processed pdf.

Comment: @VladimirF in that case the increase in size is justified

Comment: @Pablo the editor of edit 2, I know you want to do well, but if you are adding that much info, it deserves its own answer.

Comment: @don.joey can't understand why, since just extends your answer. Main thing here:  `ps2pdf` also use ghostscript, so you can use things like `-dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook`.

Comment: @PabloBianchi I think you answer is a valid alternative to mine. I like mine which is nice and short, but yours definitely has its place in the list. So please feel free to update it and add it as your own answer.

Comment: 398MB scanned pdf to 397MB!

Comment: @wbad that means that probably all possible compression is already applied, I doubt you will be able to lower the size without altering the quality

Comment: I was in a hurry and it worked like a charm, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: It didn’t work (84 MB→82 MB), but `ps2pdf -dPDFSETTING=/ebook in.pdf out.pdf` , as suggested by @PabloBianchi leads to 272 kB ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: ps2pdf -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook worked really well. 14megs down to 4. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution it was really helpful! Also is a quick way to reduce the size of pdf files. I wonder if an option like this should be included in the most popular document viewers in Linux, do you know anyone that includes this feature?

Comment: It worked! With `ps2pdf -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook input.pdf output.pdf`, a 3 pg **3.8 MB** input file which was an output from my [`pdf2searchablepdf`](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/PDF2SearchablePDF) program got reduced to **916 KB**! Note, however, that `ps2pdf input.pdf output.pdf` did nothing. This was on Ubuntu 20.04, with an original PDF already at 300 DPI to start, considering [my script ran](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/PDF2SearchablePDF/blob/master/pdf2searchablepdf.sh#L161) `pdftoppm -tiff -r 300 "$pdf_in" "$temp_dir/pg"` first.

Comment: Note: dead link :(: https://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Ps2pdf.htm#Options

Comment: Try this: https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/VectorDevices.htm#PSPDF_IN. I posted it [here too](https://gist.github.com/firstdoit/6390547#gistcomment-3573956).

Comment: To compress even further one can use `ps2pdf -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen input.pdf output.pdf`. Though quality in `/screen` option is poor than `/ebook` option.

Comment: Lmao this is so weird, it turned a bunch of the portrait pages into landscape!!!

Comment: After fixing all the rotated pages manually, this solution worked best for me. 46 MB -> 20 MB with the default command.

Answer (score 224):

If you have a **pdf with scanned images**, you can use `convert` (ImageMagick) to create a pdf with **jpeg compression** (You can use this method on any pdf, but you'll loose all text informations).

For example:

```
convert -density 200x200 -quality 60 -compress jpeg input.pdf output.pdf
```

Adjust the parameters to your needs

- *[-density](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#density)*: the pixel density in dpi (e.g. 100x100). Higher pixel densities increase quality and size
- *[-quality](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#quality)*: the compression ratio. For jpg it is between 1 to 100 with 100 the best quality, but lowest compression
- *[-compress](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#compress)*: the compression algorithm. jpeg *compression* might not be the best choice due to compression artifacts. You have the choice between BZip, Fax, Group4, JPEG, JPEG2000, Lossless, LZW, RLE or Zip as alternate compression methods (some only allow b/w images).

I was able to achieve great compression ratios for scanned/photographed documents (depending on the settings). Depending on the document source, you might want to reduce the color depth (`-depth` argument).

Comment: For a scanned document where the text is what you are interested in rather then the images and preserving depth isn't an issue, jpeg compression is not a good idea because the artifacts tend to be extremely noticeable. If you use `pdfimages input.pdf pages` to extract pbm files,  then you can do something like:  `for page in *.pbm; do convert $page -compress Group4 -type bilevel TIFF:- | convert - output.pdf`. Any OCR will be lost so I usually then do `pdfsandwich output.pdf`, which seems to reduce file size even further.

Comment: @BrianZ sure jpeg compression isn't always the best choice, but for me it was the best approach for mixed type documents. I added some informations about other compression methods to the answer.

Comment: This method ultimately uses `gs` behind the scenes.

Comment: I had to use double dash for the options to run the command `--density --quality --compress` vs `-density -quality -compress`.

Comment: If image qaulity is not the highest concern (and you just want to get that dang email attachment small enough to be sent) one might add `-resize 50%` too, change percentage depending on how much DPI was used while scanning

Comment: Could you please explain the -quality option a bit. Like how can I achieve a Low, Med and High quality compress?

Comment: @rahim.nagori I added some more information and a link with more details about the quality flag to the answer.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. I had a 5-page 62MB pdf scan and all other options (ghostscript, ps2pdf, libre office...) failed miserably. Instead it was enough to `convert -resize 30% input.pdf output.pdf` and it was shrunk to 12MB, a bit rough but still legible.

Comment: It increases my scanned pdf images: 14 MiB the original and 24MiB the converted pdf

Comment: This used to work perfectly for me. But now, with Ubuntu 20.04 and ImageMagick 6.9.10-23 Q16 x86_64, this does not work anymore. It fails with the message: "convert-im6.q16: no images defined `output.pdf' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3258"

Comment: @Nuno Seems like a policy issue, comment gs policy in `/etc/ImageMagick-7/policy.xml`

Comment: For a moderately large file this completely hogged all my CPU cores for several minutes. Not recommended.

Comment: works on Arch but Ubuntu's image magick seems to be too dumb

Comment: This was a more flexible solution than ghostscript as I was dealing with a PDF made of JPGs

Comment: This allows more fine-tuning than ghostscript by tweaking the `-density` and `-quality` options: raising one increases the size of the output, but this can be compensated by decreasing the other depending on the visual output that one needs.

Comment: I've problem with this, if the pdf size is hugh, the convert will suddenly racking up the RAM and end up being OOM.... I have 1000 scanned document, with 20GB of ram, it stuck and need force restart...

Comment: `GhostScript ps2pdf` vs. `ImageMagick convert`: 

✅ `ps2pdf` very cleanly just re-compresses the image assets.

❗️ Whereas `convert` in addition to that also adds a corresponding `smask` object (bitmap mask) to the PDF as `pdfimages -list` shows.

 This mask is redundant as is has the same pixel dimensions as the image, so effectively acts not as a mask at all, hence increases file size & rendering complexity unnecessarily.

❓ Does anyone know whether this is a bug or feature? And whether `ImageMagick convert` can be instructed to not produce such unnecessarily redundant masks?

Answer (score 72):

I needed to downsize a PDF that contained full color scans of a document.  Each of my pages was a full color image as far as the file was concerned.  They were images of pages containing text and images, but they were created by scanning to an image.

I used a combination of the below ghostscript command and one from another thread.

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dDownsampleColorImages=true \
-dColorImageResolution=150 -dNOPAUSE  -dBATCH -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf
```

This reduced the image resolution to 150dpi, cutting my file size in half.  Looking at the document, there was almost no noticeable loss of image quality.  The text is still perfectly readable on my 2012 Nexus7.

Comment: +1 for down sampling images but keeping text as vectors.  Made a huge difference in side without making my text pixelated.

Comment: Fantastic that one can tune the resolution with this command - this gave me better results than just using dPDFSETTINGS=\screen

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497120/how-to-downsample-images-within-pdf-file/9571488

Comment: +1 for the option that allows you to specify the exact resolution. Useful when you have a scanned pdf (all raster) and want to reduce the size keeping the file still readable.

Answer (score 42):

[Here is a script](http://www.alfredklomp.com/programming/shrinkpdf/) for rewriting scanned pdfs:

```
#!/bin/sh

gs  -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER \
    -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
    -dCompatibilityLevel=1.3 \
    -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen \
    -dEmbedAllFonts=true \
    -dSubsetFonts=true \
    -dColorImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic \
    -dColorImageResolution=72 \
    -dGrayImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic \
    -dGrayImageResolution=72 \
    -dMonoImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic \
    -dMonoImageResolution=72 \
    -sOutputFile=out.pdf \
     $1
```

You could customise it a bit to make it more reusable but if you only have one pdf, you could just replace `$1` with your pdf filename and bung it in a terminal.

Comment: Works a treat, thanks Oli.  You've answered pretty much everything I've asked on here so far :-D

Comment: This is a good answer but in my case at least it takes a **lot** of time to convert a somewhat large (>10Mb) PDF file (more than a minute).

Comment: I'm not sure what happens, but a 30 MB PDF results a 68 MB file. Instead of reducing, it enlarges. Same output if using directly ps2pdf as stated in next answer.

Comment: @EdVillegas The only thing I can think of (to explain that sort of increase) is that the images are of a lower resolution than the ones being generated (72dpi). Or somehow embedding the fonts is sucking in *all* the fonts.

Comment: use `pdfimages -list file.pdf` to see the native images resolution.

Answer (score 38):

1. I use *LibreOffice Draw* to open the pdf.
2. I then "export as pdf"
3. And set "jpeg compression quality" to 50% and "image resolution" to
   150 dpi

This will have a good result.

Comment: Worst possible solution to the problem! It totally messed my file up!

Comment: For my this solutions is the best, it is only necessary to configure it depends on what one wants to do. Working for my with this settings "jpeg compression quality" to 83% and "image resolution" to 150 dpi

Comment: This worked for me

Comment: I'd rather set 300 DPI and 50% compression, but it depends on the content of the pdf.

Answer (score 31):

I usually use ps2pdf to do this (easier syntax), something like this:

```
ps2pdf -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook BiggerPdf SmallerPDF
```

I use the following python script to reduce the size of all the pdf files in a dir in a production server (8.04). So it should work.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os

for fich in os.listdir('.'):
        if fich[-3:]=="pdf":
                os.system("ps2pdf -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook %s reduc/%s" % (fich,fich))
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution.  I tried Oli's first and it gave me the result I needed, but I will keep this one for future reference too.

Comment: -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer option do 50% resize.  ebook do 90% resize.

Answer (score 21):

Best for me was

```
convert -compress Zip -density 150x150 input.pdf output.pdf
```

Other ways:

```
#### gs
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=output.pdf $INPUTFILE

### pdf2ps && ps2pdf
pdf2ps input.pdf output.ps && ps2pdf output.ps output.pdf

### Webservice
http://compress.smallpdf.com/de
```

regards

Comment: Great solution. Easy to remember and it brought my pdf from 32 to 3.5 MB without sensible loss in readability.

Comment: I liked the second way
    `pdf2ps input.pdf temp.ps && ps2pdf14 temp.ps output.pdf && rm temp.ps`

Answer (score 17):

*For my other, `pdfsizeopt`-based answer, [see here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1466320/327339).*

Referencing [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/256449/327339) and [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/243753/327339), and after trying a bunch of the answers here, and doing a bunch of research and experimenting, I've come up with the following. Note that I've removed the `-dCompatibilityLevel=1.4` part of the command used in some other answers here (including [the most-upvoted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/256449/327339)) because [this table](https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/latest/VectorDevices.html#distiller-parameters) indicates that `1.5` or `1.7` are automatically used for this setting today (27 Dec. 2020), and there's no need to override those values.

### Use Ghostscript (`gs`) to compress `input.pdf` into `output.pdf`

**3 Main levels of compression:**
*Note: you may also add `-dQUIET` to suppress all output to stdout.* See: https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Use.html.

1. **Low compression**: **300 dpi** (large file size)

   ```bash
   gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH \
   -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf
   ```
2. [BEST in my testing] **Medium compression** (recommended): **150 dpi** (medium file size)

   ```bash
   gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook   -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH \
   -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf
   ```
3. **High compression**: **72 dpi** (small file size--may produce grainy or unreadable results in *some* cases, so try it and give it a shot)

   ```bash
   gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen  -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH \
   -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf
   ```

You can also add `time` in front of the command to see how long it takes (this works with *any* Linux command). Sample output:

```bash
$ time gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sOutputFile=out.pdf in.pdf
GPL Ghostscript 9.50 (2019-10-15)
Copyright (C) 2019 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
see the file COPYING for details.
Processing pages 1 through 15.
Page 1
Loading NimbusSans-Regular font from /usr/share/ghostscript/9.50/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Regular... 5205104 3852122 2872760 1487237 3 done.
Page 2
Page 3
Page 4
Page 5
Page 6
Page 7
Page 8
Page 9
Page 10
Page 11
Page 12
Page 13
Page 14
Page 15

real    0m1.326s
user    0m1.142s
sys     0m0.048s
```

If you add `-dQUIET` to the command, *none* of the Ghostscript output is shown, and you get this (when using `time` in front):

```bash
$ time gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dQUIET -sOutputFile=out.pdf in.pdf

real    0m1.018s
user    0m0.976s
sys     0m0.040s
```

You can also use `ps2pdf`, which is a wrapper around `gs`, and produces very similar, but not exactly identical, results. *I prefer to just use `gs` directly, as shown above, however.*

1. Low compression: **300 dpi** (large file size)

   ```bash
   ps2pdf -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer input.pdf output.pdf
   ```
2. Medium compression (recommended): **150 dpi** (medium file size)

   ```bash
   ps2pdf -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook   input.pdf output.pdf
   ```
3. High compression: **72 dpi** (small file size--may produce grainy or unreadable results in *some* cases, so try it and give it a shot)

   ```bash
   ps2pdf -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen  input.pdf output.pdf
   ```

### PDF Compression Tests

Testing the `gs` commands above on output from my [`pdf2searchablepdf` script here](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/PDF2SearchablePDF), I see the following:

1. Low compression: has no significant effect since my script already produces 300 dpi output PDFs. So, a **3.8 MB** 3 pg input PDF results in an output PDF of **~3.8MB**.
2. [BEST] Medium compression: compresses the file nicely! A  **3.8 MB** 3 pg input PDF results in an output PDF of **~0.95MB**.
3. High compression: may be too much. A **3.8 MB** 3 pg input PDF results in an output PDF of **~0.37MB**, BUT in my particular test is *completely unreadable*, since the input PDF was already of somewhat poor resolution to begin with. If you begin with a high quality/high resolution input PDF, you may have much better, readable results.

### Ghostscript (`gs`) Documentation:

For all `-d` ("`d`efine") `PDFSETTINGS` available, see here: https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/latest/VectorDevices.html#controls-and-features-specific-to-postscript-and-pdf-input. I have quoted that section below, except that I've *added the DPI values for each setting in **bold**, as taken [from this table here](https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/latest/VectorDevices.html#distiller-parameters)*. You can refer to that table to see the dozens of lower-level settings chosen by `gs` for each `PDFSETTINGS` option.

> #### Controls and features specific to PostScript and PDF input
>
> `-dPDFSETTINGS=configuration`
>
> Presets the "distiller parameters" to one of four predefined settings:
>
> - `/screen` **(72 dpi)** selects low-resolution output similar to the Acrobat Distiller (up to version X) "Screen Optimized" setting.
> - `/ebook` **(150 dpi)** selects medium-resolution output similar to the Acrobat Distiller (up to version X) "eBook" setting.
> - `/printer` **(300 dpi)** selects output similar to the Acrobat Distiller "Print Optimized" (up to version X) setting.
> - `/prepress` **(300 dpi)** selects output similar to Acrobat Distiller "Prepress Optimized" (up to version X) setting.
> - `/default` **(72 dpi)** selects output intended to be useful across a wide variety of uses, possibly at the expense of a larger output file.

You can also see definitions for various options on this page: https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Use.html:

> `-dNOPAUSE`
> Disables the prompt and pause at the end of each page. Normally one should use this (along with `-dBATCH`) when producing output on a printer or to a file; it also may be desirable for applications where another program is "driving" Ghostscript.
>
> `-dBATCH`
> Causes Ghostscript to exit after processing all files named on the command line, rather than going into an interactive loop reading PostScript commands. Equivalent to putting `-c quit` at the end of the command line.
>
> `-dQUIET`
> Suppresses routine information comments on standard output. This is currently necessary when redirecting device output to standard output.

Answer (score 13):

I strongly recommend **[`pdfsizeopt`](https://github.com/pts/pdfsizeopt)**.

It is much more efficient in terms of size reduction than any of the previous CLI and GUI software that I have tried (including `convert`, `gs`, `pdftk`, etc.) — although possibly slower with `pngout` activated —, and does not have some of their issues (no heavily pixelated/degraded images, no loss of metadata such as table of contents, etc.).

Now, if you need to attain a certain size whatever the consequences (inc. degrading images to a point of unreadability), it might not be the tool you need, but as an always-working go-to solution, to reduce unnecessary big sizes in PDFs without loosing in readability, information and acceptable image quality, I think it is the best option. (Note: I tend to use it after having first done a vectorization-OCR in Adobe Acrobat [the function used to be called "CleanScan"], which can have a dramatical size impact on some scanned text documents.)

---

I recommend the [generic Unix install](https://github.com/pts/pdfsizeopt):

1. Install all required dependencies:

   - [Ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/)
   - [jbig2](https://github.com/pts/pdfsizeopt-jbig2)
   - [pngout](http://www.jonof.id.au/kenutils)
   - [png22pnm](https://github.com/pts/tif22pnm)
   - [sam2p](https://github.com/pts/sam2p)
2. Download and install the executable:

   ```bash
   curl -L -o pdfsizeopt.single https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pts/pdfsizeopt/master/pdfsizeopt.single
   chmod +x pdfsizeopt.single
   cp pdfsizeopt.single /usr/local/bin/pdfsizeopt
   ```

Usage:

```bash
pdfsizeopt original.pdf [compressed.pdf]
```

---

Note: for **Mac** users finding this post (or Linuxbrew users), there is a Homebrew install formula:

```bash
brew install --HEAD pts/utils/pdfsizeopt
```

Comment: what MARVELOUS GEM of a software! Thank you very much for reccomending this :-)

Comment: No luck. Running `pdfsizeopt` on a 3.8 MB 3pg 300 DPI output PDF file from my [`pdf2searchablepdf`](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/PDF2SearchablePDF) script, the size remained 3.8 MB (it got smaller by a few KB is all).

Comment: @GabrielStaples: `pdfsizeopt` will not always reduce filesize significantly. If that is what I'm after (strongest reduction), I use other software (e.g., [PDF Squeezer](https://www.witt-software.com/pdfsqueezer/)) that reduces image quality more drastically. `pdfsizeopt` is my default CLI solution for batch PDF resizing.

Comment: For anyone struggling to install the `jbig2`, `pngout`, and `sam2p` dependencies, I've detailed full installation instructions for those [in my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1466320/327339).

Answer (score 6):

I just encountered this problem myself. If using simple scan, select text mode for low resolution scans and you won't need to worry about the command line stuff. Just saying.

Comment: This is the single answer in this thread that solved my problem. I downplayed Simplescan, but it really was the answer for me, instead of fighting against Xsane in what seemed to be an endless agony.

Answer (score 6):

Control the compression quality:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
INPUT=$1; shift
OUTPUT=$1; shift
GS_BIN=/usr/bin/gs
QFACTOR="0.40"

# Image Compression Quality
#
# Quality HSamples VSamples QFactor
# Minimum [2 1 1 2] [2 1 1 2] 2.40
# Low     [2 1 1 2] [2 1 1 2] 1.30
# Medium  [2 1 1 2] [2 1 1 2] 0.76
# High    [1 1 1 1] [1 1 1 1] 0.40
# Maximum [1 1 1 1] [1 1 1 1] 0.15 

${GS_BIN} -dBATCH -dSAFER -DNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=${OUTPUT} -c "<< /ColorImageDict << /QFactor ${QFACTOR} /Blend 1 /HSample [1 1 1 1] /VSample [1 1 1 1] >> >> setdistillerparams" -f ${INPUT}
```

Comment: ...so both INPUT and OUTPUT are the same argument? You might want to add usage guidelines.

Comment: Note the `shift`. First parameter is input file, second is the output file and rest of the parameters will be passed to `gs` as is.

Comment: I think you want /HSample**s** and /VSample**s**, not /HSample and /VSample. See e.g. [ps2pdf docs](https://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Ps2pdf.htm#note_7) or the PostScript language reference manual. Also perhaps worth noting that the allowed QFactor range is 0 to 1,000,000 and lower values produce higher quality.

Answer (score 6):

For me the gs `screen` option was too bad, and the `ebook` one too big.

My original document contained text as colour and black and white images (depending on the page).

The best solution I did come up has been:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dDownsampleColorImages=true -dDownsampleGrayImages=true -dDownsampleMonoImages=true -dColorImageResolution=130 -dGrayImageResolution=130 -dMonoImageResolution=130 -r130 -dNOPAUSE  -dBATCH -sOutputFile=output_lr.pdf input.pdf
```

Note that the compression level is not linear.. if I was specifying 135 it didn't compressed, I did find 130 to be (in my case) the maximum resolution that achieves a compression.

Comment: The fact that specifying a target resolution of 135 didn’t reduce the file size is likely because of the `ColorImageDownsampleThreshold` option (and the other two for gray and monochrome), which defaults to 1.5 and tells ghostscript not to reduce the resolution of images whose resolution is not at least 1.5 times the target resolution. Your PDF probably contained images at 200 dpi, for which a target resolution of 135 dpi is a 1.48x decrease, but 130 dpi a 1.54x decrease.

 That’s probably because

Answer (score 5):

Since this link was first for me when I searched in Google, I thought I'd add one more possibility.  None of the above solutions was working for me on a pdf exported from Inkscape (15 mb), but I was at last able to shrink it down to 1 mb by opening it in GIMP, and exporting as pdf again.

Another option that came close (but text was a little fuzzy) was ImageMagick's convert utility:

```
convert -compress Zip input.pdf output.pdf
```

Comment: I guess this is what you meant by "a little fuzzy", but just to clarify, `convert -compress Zip` appeared to rasterise all vectors.

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same problem, and was glad to find this thread. Specifically I had a pdf generated from scanned images, and needed to reduce its byte size by a factor of 6.

Unfortunately, none of the solutions above worked :(. Then I realized that somewhere in the scanner->jpeg->pdf process the size of the page had gotten bloated by a factor of aprx 4. The documents I scanned were all Letter sized, but the pdf had size of

```
identify -verbose doc_orig.pdf | grep "Print size"
 Print size: 35.4167x48.7222
```

I got the desired results finally with a "convert" command that did both resizing as well as compression steps in one:

```
convert -density 135x135 -quality 70 -compress jpeg -resize 22.588% doc_orig.pdf doc_lowres.pdf
```

Note that doc_orig had density of 72x72 dpi.

Comment: Your answer is a life saver, Kalpit. I was faced with the same problem, and nothing else was even making a dent in the file size. By resizing my pages, I went from 40MB to 2MB. Hurray!

Answer (score 4):

In the end I wrote my own bash script to solve this, it uses `mogrify`, `convert` and `gs` to extract pdf pages as png, resize them, convert them to 1-bit bmp and then rebuild them as pdf. File size reduction can be over 90%. Available at http://www.timedicer.co.uk/programs/help/pdf-compress.sh.php.

Answer (score 3):

If converting to djvu would also be ok and if no colors are involved, you could try the following:

Convert the pdf to jpg files using `pdfimages -j`

If you get pbm files instead, you should do the intermediate step:

`for FILENAME in $(ls *.pbm); do convert $FILENAME ${FILENAME%.*}.jpg ;done`

The convert command is from the imagemagick package.

Then use [scantailor](http://scantailor.sourceforge.net/) to make tif's out of it.

In a last step you go to scantailors out direcory (where the tif's are located) and apply [djvubind](http://jwilk.net/software/ocrodjvu) to that directory.

This should reduce the filesize drastically without big quality loss of the text. If you want finer control over the ocr-backend, you may try `djvubind --no-ocr` and use ocrodjvu to add the ocr layer afterwards.

If you have color's in your document things get a bit more complicated. Instead of [djvubind](http://code.google.com/p/djvubind/) you could use [didjvu](http://code.google.com/p/didjvu/) and in scantailor you have to change to mixed mode and select sometimes color-images manually.

Answer (score 2):

load image or even pdf file into inkscape.

From inkscape: Save in vector format (as the native .svg).

Import vector files into scribus, edit layout and export/save as .pdf from there

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

```bash
$ time pdftk myFile.pdf output myFile__SMALLER.pdf compress
GC Warning: Repeated allocation of very large block (appr. size 16764928):
    May lead to memory leak and poor performance.
GC Warning: Repeated allocation of very large block (appr. size 8384512):
    May lead to memory leak and poor performance.
GC Warning: Repeated allocation of very large block (appr. size 11837440):
    May lead to memory leak and poor performance.
GC Warning: Repeated allocation of very large block (appr. size 8384512):
    May lead to memory leak and poor performance.
GC Warning: Repeated allocation of very large block (appr. size 33525760):
    May lead to memory leak and poor performance.
GC Warning: Repeated allocation of very large block (appr. size 7254016):
    May lead to memory leak and poor performance.
GC Warning: Repeated allocation of very large block (appr. size 34041856):
    May lead to memory leak and poor performance.
GC Warning: Repeated allocation of very large block (appr. size 33525760):
    May lead to memory leak and poor performance.

real    0m23.677s
user    0m23.142s
sys     0m0.540s
$ du myFile*.pdf
108M    myFile.pdf
74M     myFile__SMALLER.pdf
```

It is faster than `gs` but compresses upto 30% in this case for a 107.5MiB input file.

Comment: No luck for me. On Ubuntu 20.04 on a searchable output PDF file from my [`pdf2searchablepdf`](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/PDF2SearchablePDF) program, the output file was identical in size to the input file.

Answer (score 2):

I use this zsh function for compressing scanned documents:

```
pdf-compress-gray () {
    local input="${1}"
    local out="${2:-${input:r}_cg.pdf}"
    local dpi="${pdf_compress_gray_dpi:-90}"

    gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sProcessColorModel=DeviceGray -sColorConversionStrategy=Gray -dDownsampleColorImages=true -dOverrideICC -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -dColorImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic -dColorImageResolution=$dpi -dGrayImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic -dGrayImageResolution=$dpi -dMonoImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic -dMonoImageResolution=$dpi -sOutputFile="$out" "$input"
}
```

Usage:

```
[pdf_compress_gray_dpi=100] pdf-compress-gray input.pdf [output.pdf]
```

Answer (score 2):

I normally simply use

```
gs -dQUIET -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer \
   -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf
```

I went through many questions one how to reduce the size of a pdf on AskUbuntu, Stack Overflow and Unix & Linux SE and I wondered what all those options
proposed in the answers meant.

Some are [Interaction-related parameters](https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Use.html#interaction-related-parameters):

```
-dQUIET
-dBATCH
-dNOPAUSE
```

Some are [Device and output selection parameters](https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Use.html#device-and-output-selection-parameters):

```
-sDEVICE
-sOutputFile
```

Some are [Common controls and features](https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/latest/VectorDevices.html#the-family-of-pdf-and-postscript-output-devices) specific to device PDFWRITE:

```
-r<resolution>
-dCompressFonts
```

This important one [presets the "Distiller Parameters"](https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/latest/VectorDevices.html#controls-and-features-specific-to-postscript-and-pdf-input), Adobe's documented parameters for controlling the conversion into PDF, to one of four predefined settings (screen, ebook, printer, prepress)

```
-dPDFSETTINGS
```

All the ones below are automatically preset according to `-dPDFSETTINGS`, as per [this table](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/VectorDevices.htm#distillerparams). A command suggest by [Kurt Pfeifle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11851460/4547005) can be used to check these values. You can fine tune them if you want:

```
-dCompatibilityLevel
-dAutoRotatePages
-dEmbedAllFonts
-dSubsetFonts
-sColorConversionStrategy
-dDownsampleColorImages
-dDownsampleGrayImages
-dDownsampleMonoImages
-dColorImageResolution
-dGrayImageResolution
-dMonoImageResolution
-dColorImageDownsampleType
-dGrayImageDownsampleType
-dMonoImageDownsampleType
```

Answer (score 1):

Super simple PDF compress tool: [GitHub page.](https://github.com/john-francis96/pdf-compressor)

Installation on Ubuntu:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jfswitz/released

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install pdf-compressor
```

It uses ghostscript.

Comment: This is a GUI tool, no?

Answer (score 1):

### `pdfsizeopt` full installation instructions

*For my other, `gs`-based answer, [see here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1303196/327339).*

For anyone trying to follow [@iNyar's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1011292/327339) to install and try out the [`pdfsizeopt`](https://github.com/pts/pdfsizeopt) tool, installing the dependencies is tricky. If you run the tool with*out* installing all dependencies, `pdfsizeopt` won't run. Here are the errors I got when trying to run it with*out* `jbig2`, `pngout`, and `sam2p` installed:

```bash
$ ./pdfsizeopt in.pdf out.pdf
info: This is pdfsizeopt ZIP rUNKNOWN size=69856.
info: prepending to PATH: /home/gabriel/GS/Jobs/Edge Autonomy/Onboarding [29 May 2023 start date!]
error: image optimizer not found on PATH: jbig2
error: image optimizer not found on PATH: pngout
error: image optimizer not found on PATH: sam2p
error: image optimizer not found on PATH: sam2p
fatal: not all image optimizers found (see above), ignore with --do-require-image-optimizers=no
```

So, the solution is to install the `jbig2`, `pngout`, and `sam2p` dependencies manually. Here are the full installation instructions, therefore, for `pdfsizeopt`:

*Tested in Linux Ubuntu 20.04.*

```bash
# ================================================
# 1. Install `pdfsizeopt` dependencies
# ================================================

# --------------------
# jbig2:
# - https://github.com/agl/jbig2enc
# --------------------

# install dependencies
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install libleptonica-dev

git clone https://github.com/agl/jbig2enc.git
cd jbig2enc
./autogen.sh
./configure
time make  
sudo make install 
# ensure it is installed
jbig2 --version

# --------------------
# pngout
# - http://advsys.net/ken/utils.htm#pngout
#   - http://www.jonof.id.au/kenutils.html
# --------------------

# download it
wget https://www.jonof.id.au/files/kenutils/pngout-20200115-linux-static.tar.gz
# extract it
tar -xf pngout-20200115-linux-static.tar.gz
cd pngout-20200115-linux-static
# install it
sudo cp -i amd64/pngout-static /usr/local/bin/pngout
# ensure it's installed
pngout

# --------------------
# sam2p
# - https://github.com/pts/sam2p
# --------------------

# install dependencies
sudo apt install libgif-dev

# go here and find the latest release:
# https://github.com/pts/sam2p/releases
# Use the correct URL from there in the following commands.

# download it
wget https://github.com/pts/sam2p/releases/download/v0.49.4/sam2p-0.49.4.tar.gz
# extract it
tar -xf sam2p-0.49.4.tar.gz
cd sam2p-0.49.4
./configure
time make
sudo make install 
# ensure it's installed by checking its version
sam2p --version

# ================================================
# 2. Install `pdfsizeopt`
# ================================================

curl -L -o pdfsizeopt https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pts/pdfsizeopt/master/pdfsizeopt.single
chmod +x pdfsizeopt
sudo cp -i pdfsizeopt /usr/local/bin/pdfsizeopt
```

Now use it:

```bash
# 1. Check the help menu to ensure it's installed
pdfsizeopt --help 2>&1 | less -RFX

# 2. Use it to optimize in.pdf into out.pdf
pdfsizeopt in.pdf out.pdf
```

Example run and output:

```bash
$ pdfsizeopt in.pdf out.pdf
info: This is pdfsizeopt ZIP rUNKNOWN size=69734.
info: prepending to PATH: /home/gabriel/Downloads/Install_Files/pdfsizeopt/pdfsizeopt/pdfsizeopt_libexec
info: loading PDF from: in.pdf
info: loaded PDF of 1955931 bytes
info: separated to 18 objs + xref + trailer
info: parsed 18 objs
info: found 0 Type1 fonts loaded
info: found 0 Type1C fonts loaded
info: optimized 6 streams, kept 6 zip
info: compressed 0 streams, kept 0 of them uncompressed
info: saving PDF with 18 objs to: out.pdf
info: generated object stream of 523 bytes in 9 objects (21%)
info: generated 1953795 bytes (100%)
```

Result of running `pdfsizeopt` above: no change. `in.pdf` is 2.0 MB, and `out.pdf` is 2.0 MB. Then again, `gs`, as described [in my other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1303196/327339), didn't work on this particular PDF either. I don't know why.
Note: for anyone who wants to experiment with this, here is how I created the PDF I'm experimenting on:

1. Take 3 photos with your phone (Google Pixel 5 in my case). Let Google Photos upload them to the cloud.
2. Download them into a directory.
3. Run [`pdf2searchablepdf -c "path/to/dir"`](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/PDF2SearchablePDF) on that dir with the 3 images, to perform OCR on them and combine them into a single PDF. You'll see that

   1. My "compressed" PDF output, using `gs` under-the-hood, did nothing.
   2. All files are the same size, even though one should be large, medium, small, etc.
4. Try to compress them with `pdfsizeopt` and it does nothing for me on these PDFs as well.

### References:

1. [@iNyar's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1011292/327339)
2. ChatGpt helped me a ton to figure out how to install a lot of this mess, in particular calling `sudo apt install libgif-dev` prior to running `time make` to build `sam2p`, else I'd get this error:

   ```bash
   g++ -s -O2 -DHAVE_CONFIG2_H   -fsigned-char -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -ansi -pedantic -Wall -W -Wextra -c gensi.cpp
   g++ -s   sam2p_main.o appliers.o crc32.o in_ps.o in_tga.o in_pnm.o in_bmp.o in_gif.o in_lbm.o in_xpm.o mapping.o in_pcx.o in_jai.o in_png.o in_jpeg.o in_tiff.o rule.o minips.o encoder.o pts_lzw.o pts_fax.o pts_defl.o error.o image.o gensio.o snprintf.o gensi.o -o sam2p
   /usr/bin/ld: appliers.o: in function `out_gif89a_work(GenBuffer::Writable&, Rule::OutputRule*, Image::SampledInfo*)':
   appliers.cpp:(.text+0x2025): undefined reference to `out_gif_write(GenBuffer::Writable&, Image::Indexed*)'
   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
   make: *** [Makedep:66: sam2p] Error 1
   ```

   All words and commands in this answer are my own, however, and I tested everything in this answer personally.

Answer (score 0):

I used below commands but it didnt compress my pdf file substantially. Some times some of the portion was blackened after compression.

1. `gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=output.pdf $INPUTFILE`
2. `"ps2pdf -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook %s %s" % (input_file_path, out_file_path)`

After too much wandering over the web I just couldn't find the right compression library. I came across `pdfcompressor.com`. This is just awesome website. It compresses the pdf by 95% ( 15Mb of files). So I used selenium and Tor to automate the compression. Checkout my Github Repository. 
[GITHUB] (https://github.com/gugli28/PdfCompressor)