# How to reduce the size of a pdf file?

Tags: pdf, compression, ghostscript

I'm looking for a way in Ubuntu to reduce the size of a pdf (by reducing the quality of the images).

I know that this can be done in Ghostscript by typing the following command in terminal:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf
```

The problem is that I can't specify the quality with any accuracy. The parameter `-dPDFSETTINGS=/screen` is the one that decides the quality; but the alternatives are quite rigid (for example it is possible to do `-dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook` for slightly better quality).

I'm looking for a way to reduce the size of a pdf in a way that allows me to specify the desired quality numerically.

Comment: You might want to check this Q&A out: [GUI program to resize pdf documents and change their DPI](http://askubuntu.com/questions/280312/gui-program-to-resize-pdf-documents-and-change-their-dpi/280406)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I reduce the file size of a scanned PDF file?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/113544/how-can-i-reduce-the-file-size-of-a-scanned-pdf-file)

Comment: related question: [How to analyze the space usage within pdf document?](https://superuser.com/questions/685997/how-to-analyze-the-space-usage-within-pdf-document)

Answer (score 96):

I was able to make a slight variation on your command successful using the -r300 option from @drN  The -r option allows you to set the output resolution in the pdf as well as png.

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/default \
    -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -dDetectDuplicateImages \
    -dCompressFonts=true -r150 -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf
```

Edit: Newer versions now prevalaent of gs have a shorter syntax:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/default \
    -dQUIET -dDetectDuplicateImages \
    -dCompressFonts=true -r150 -o output.pdf input.pdf
```

Thanks @pierre-adrien

Comment: This command transformed a 25MB 4-pages PDF into the *almost* same quality one, but 2MB. Cheers!

Comment: This works with most files. However, in some cases it actually increases the file size. It seems the `-r` option is ignored in these cases.

Comment: This command consumed all of my RAM (8Gb) and froze my laptop with a 1000page pdf file.

Comment: This didn't work for me. No matter what value I use with `-r`, it always gives me an output with approximately the same size as the original (I am compress to convert a scanned PDF).

Comment: For a shorter command, you could replace `-dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf` with `-o output.pdf input.pdf`  (`-o` switch documentation: https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/gs10.0.0/Use.html#o-switch)

Answer (score 36):

The simplest way I found is to open the source PDF file with LibreOffice Draw and then export to PDF with the expected DPI.

The export dialog window of Draw allows you to specify the DPI and other options for the exported PDF.

Comment: I tried all the other command line things, but in the end, this allowed me to raise the compression enough for my purposes.

Comment: The graphical way, with still a lot of control.

Comment: I found out that LibreOffice Draw is better at printing/exporting pdf than just about anything else, so +1.

Comment: For large-font documents like certificates a **DPI of 100** and **JPEG compression of 80%** seems to produce the best size-quality trade-off. I could reduce a 12 MB document to 110KB.

Comment: Wow, this is a very simple and yet effective solution: I just reduced a scanned PDF from 49 MB to <4MB!

Answer (score 13):

These two posts that I had posted on Stackoverflow should help you. I was trying to reduce the size of pdfs whilst ensuring that they met a certain dpi or ppi for my thesis.

[Reducing size of pdf with ghostscript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11850776/957560)

[Changing pdf image dpi using gs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9625967/957560)

Have you tried playing around with `convert` in Linux?

### Edit:

```
gs \
  -o out300.png \
  -sDEVICE=pngalpha \
  -r300 \
   input.pdf
```

If I remember correctly, `r300` is the output `dpi` but you might want to check. This converts a pdf to a png, though.

OR

```
convert -units PixelsPerInch myPic.pdf -density 300 fileout.pdf
```

Let us know how it goes! This is for a pdf or any other format to any other format. I just used an input file of myPic.pdf and an output file of fileout.pdf

Comment: Hmm... I looked at the questions you linked to. They are interesting, but it is difficult to eke out a concrete command that I should use. I'm looking for a command with some numerical value there that I can play with that will determine the quality. Can you effect such a command? Can one do it using convert?

Comment: I editted my answer to include some more simpler options. Take a look and let us know! `:)`

Comment: The convert increases my pdf size, even if I use a 100 dpi. Maybe the best choice is to convert to png using "gs" and then "convert" to go to pdf?

Comment: @Nicole There have always been issues with pdf conversions. What do you propose to use the pdf for?

Comment: @Nicole I noticed that to get the best result for pdfs/eps files, I'd have to go back to the program that made the pdf in the first place and change my save options to save in the dpi/ppi that I want. I hope that helps and yes that can be a bit of a pain the backside.

Answer (score 11):

If reducing the size of the file is your primary objective (and *not* only reducing size of the figures and also *not* to specify the quality numerically), how about `ps2pdf`:

```sh
ps2pdf input.pdf output.pdf
```

Depending on the characteristics of the PDF, this can reduce the file size by an order of magnitude.

Comment: Amazing suggestion.  So easy, and my PDF just went from 13.7 MB to 2.5 MB - and it still looks the same to me!

Answer (score 4):

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=myNewFile.pdf myOldFile.pdf
```

This is the easiest way I think, can reduce the size to 50+/- kb.
On your terminal, go to the directory of the file: example

```
cd ~/document/files
```

Then type the above code where:

```
myNewFile.pdf
```

is the file's new name and

```
myOldFile.pdf
```

is the name of the file.

Answer (score 0):

From [my answer to a similar Unix & Linux Stack Exchange question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/749382/486275):

> If the PDF file consists entirely of image data;
>
> ```
> pdftk inputFile.pdf burst
> mogrify -density 300 -format jpg -quality 20 pg_*.pdf
> convert *.jpg -auto-orient outputFile.pdf
> ```
>
> The density value can match the density of the source image (eg 300
> dpi), but the jpeg quality should be lower than the source image (e.g.
> 20).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ocrmypdf](https://ocrmypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook.html#improving-ocr-quality) `--oversample <DPI>` flag to reduce the size of the pdf.

For example:

```bash
ocrmypdf --skip-text --oversample 150 input.pdf output.pdf
```

I usually like to do this:

```bash
ocrmypdf --skip-text --oversample 150 input.pdf input.pdf
```

to save time for renaming the pdf file. I chose dpi to be 150 as reference to [ghostscript](https://ghostscript.com/docs/9.54.0/VectorDevices.htm#distillerparams) flag `-dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `gs` command as suggested by others, but make sure you change `dPDFSETTINGS` to either `screen`, for low quality images (75 dpi), or `ebook`, for 150 dpi.

Here's a full list of the `dPDFSETTINGS` to choose from (based on this [link](https://community.claris.com/en/s/question/0D53w0000680OtlCAE/best-recommendations-for-linux-server-doing-compression-on-pdf-files-it-creates)):

- `-dPDFSETTINGS=/screen` — Low quality and small size at 72dpi.
- `-dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook` — Slightly better quality but also a larger file size at 150dpi.
- `-dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress` — High quality and large size at 300 dpi.

_ `-dPDFSETTINGS=/default` — System chooses the best output, which can create larger PDF files.

You use a command like the following:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook \                                                                                                                                     
    -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -dDetectDuplicateImages \
    -dCompressFonts=true -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pdf2ps large.pdf very_large.ps
ps2pdf very_large.ps small.pdf
```