# Reduce size of printed-to-PDF files

Tags: pdf

I have a niche Java app that I use extensively (since it's Java and thus basically cross-platform, and since it can cater to my needs), and its job is to produce a printed page with text on it.

However, I need to distribute those printed pages electronically, and thus I installed the `printer-driver-cups-pdf` package, which gives me a PDF printer, and thus I can distribute PDF's to my team members.

However, these "printed" PDF's are enormous. A 2-page PDF is easily 800kb, and three pages are well over 1MB. This is a problem, since I cannot easily e-mail 10 of these documents to someone quickly.

Exporting a page with around the same amount of text within LibreOffice results in PDF files at least 10 times smaller.

**Does anyone have any suggestions?**

I cannot use image compression, since these pages contain only vectors.

Incidentally, I am using Ubuntu 15.10.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I have already tried Ghostscript with various `-dPDFSETTINGS=/` settings. That, however, does not work, since it only applies to raster images. I have also tried converting to/from SVG, PS and EPS. I am still stuck with preposterously huge vector PDF files.

Comment: IIRC you don't need to use the CUPS PDF printer. There should be a save to file option in the print dialog anyway.

Comment: @muru That depends on how the program handles the printing, I would not assume that.

Comment: @muru Unfortunately, because this is a Java app, it uses a Java print dialog, which has no Save-To-File option. I am still stuck with `printer-driver-cups-pdf` ...

Comment: Maybe you could try adjusting the CUPS PDF resolution via the CUPS web interface (`https://localhost:631`), or use Ghostscript or something to compress the PDF: http://askubuntu.com/q/113544/158442

Comment: @MeerLin can we just delete these off-topic comments?

Comment: Is your Java program open source by any chance? A workaround might be to edit the program to write the output to a file instead of printing it.

Comment: @MeerLin I wish it was. Some people are looking into creating open-source alternatives, but those could be months or years away... :-(

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/401176/reducing-the-file-size-of-pdfs-generated-with-cups-pdf

Answer (score 3):

`cups-pdf` [has been broken for a long time](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups-pdf/+bug/366949).  It produces very large PDF files that encapsulate images and do not support text selection (for copy-paste).

A decent alternative is the [Tea4CUPS](https://wiki.debian.org/Tea4CUPS#Virtual_PDF_printer.) virtual printer.

It works well most of the time for me, but sometimes printing with Tea4CUPS will abort -- in those cases, I resort to the Ubuntu built-in Print to File option.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ghostscript can help you compress your PDFs, as it will reduce their size and also optimize them for viewing them on screen rather than on paper:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen \
-dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=out.pdf in.pdf
```

Alternatively maybe the answers to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113544/how-can-i-reduce-the-file-size-of-a-scanned-pdf-file) question might be helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately, for reasons unknown to me, because these files contain only vectors, the new files that ghostscript creates are even larger. Sorry, but I did try that...

Comment: @etsnyman Did you have a look on the link I provided?

Comment: Yes, I have looked. Everything there seems to compress/optimize rasters, not vectors.

Comment: @etsnyman mention what you have tried in the question, then.

Comment: @muru I did specifically mention that I cannot use image compression as it will not work. I didn't feel like listing the 5-6 different options I have tried.

Comment: @etsnyman mention them anyway. Nobody cares what you feel. You want us to help, we don't want to waste time suggesting things you have already tried.