# How to print a pdf file to pdf including annotations and force rasterization from the terminal

Tags: command-line, printing, pdf

What I actually want to achieve is, the result I get when printing to pdf from Okular and clicking on force rasterization and print annotations. However, I would like to do this from the terminal (my ultimate goal is to create a dolphin service menu for this).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert seems to rasterize pdfs on the terminal. So
`convert -density 300 infile.pdf outfile.pdf` would do the trick. Convert is provided by Imagemagick , so you would need to install that first. The file will be quite large but you can reduce its size with gostscript (e.g. `gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=outfile.pdf infile.pdf` or by trying some other answer from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113544/how-can-i-reduce-the-file-size-of-a-scanned-pdf-file/3410#3410))

A service menu for the rasterization would look like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Service
ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin
MimeType=application/pdf
Icon=acroread
Actions=rasterizepdf;

[Desktop Action rasterizepdf]
Name=rasterize pdf
Icon=acroread
Exec=convert -density 300 %u "$(dirname "%u")/$(basename "%u" .pdf)_r.pdf"
```

Save it in `~/.local/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/` as a .desktop file. Of course you can also create a service menu for shrinking the pdf afterwards.