# Show input filename within output filename — after ghostscript command

Tags: command-line, bash, filename, ghostscript

I use this script (from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/256449/925128)) in order to reduce the size of a pdf file:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook \ -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf
```

I have added this within a Dolphin action (service menu) with the line:

```
Exec=bash -c 'pdf=$(gs -dQUIET -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook    -sOutputFile=ebook.pdf "%u"); kdialog --title "Shrink" --msgbox "Done! $pdf";';
```

I would like the output file name to be automatically based on that of the input file, something like: `input_xxx`.

Comment: I'd try something like `f="%u"; pdf=$(gs ... -sOutputFile="${f%.pdf}_xxx}" "$f"); ...`

Comment: @steeldriver - that's the answer. Could you post it as such? (Only, instead of `"${f%.pdf}_xxx}"`, it should be `"${f%.pdf}_xxx"`.)

Comment: Ooops sorry about that - done

Comment: I meant `"${f%.pdf}_xxx.pdf"` for my specific script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assign the `%u` value to a shell variable, it should be possible to use standard variable expansion syntax `${var%.ext}_xxx` to remove the `.pdf` extension and add a suffix of your choice:

```
bash -c 'f="%u"; pdf=$(gs -dQUIET -dBATCH [pdf options] -sOutputFile="${f%.pdf}_xxx" "$f"); ...'
```